# Identification and question about possible sickness / parasite

Tags: identification

I got this plant a couple of weeks ago. The leaves were all soft and roots partly rotten.

I decided to cut away some roots, put it into new soil (not pasteurized though), cut away almost all leaves and put it in a bright spot. I gave it very little water first until the soil dried out, then I started watering slowly.

It grew some fresh green leaves, but they too are rather soft and weak. It doesn't seem to take much water in at all.

My questions:

- Which plant is this?
- What's it's ailment, some bacterial infection maybe?
- What are the long excrescences that I marked?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From its general appearance and the scalloped edges to the leaves, this appears to be what's commonly known as an Easter cactus, or Schlumbergera gaertnerii (previously Rhipsalidopsis gaertneri, and I think its recently been through another name change to Hatiori gaertneri). The 'excrescences' are adventitious roots, and these sometimes form when a plant is very stressed in its current environment.

These plants are cacti, but they're forest types, meaning they grow in relatively humid, shady forest type conditions rather than hot, arid and sunny situations. It's hard to say whether the plant is still suffering, despite the new growth, because of environmental conditions or because the central core of the plant has a problem - I suspect its more environmental though because the simple fact you have new growth means, despite its appearance, its still a viable plant. It might be worth trying to propagate a part of one of the stems separately - instructions for that are included in the link below, along with other information and care instructions

http://www.ourhouseplants.com/plants/eastercactus